# NSWindow - Deactivate on Hide - isVisible

Tags: cocoa, hide, nswindow, visible

I have an NSWindow with a "Hide on deactivate" set to TRUE.

When my application looses focus, the window disappears, however, testing that by "isVisible" gives TRUE.
What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isVisible == YES` means that your window is still present on the screen or miniaturized to Dock.

Well, I never used this option before... But, if you really want to hide the window when your app loses focus, implement `-applicationDidResignActive:` method of `NSApplicationDelegate` and call `-orderOut:` for your window.

That will give you a stable result.